# jQuery Create dynamic contextmenu loaded using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, contextmenu

I'm using the below context menu plugin for jQuery 1.8.11.js and using the "build" callback to dynamically create the menu on every right click.

http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html

I'd like to be able to load the menu options dynamically when an item is clicked.

My problem is that this contextmenu doesn't contain any items after ajax calls.

This is jQuery code:

```
    $(function(){
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu-one ul li',
            build: function($trigger, e) {
            var str = $trigger.text();
            var replaced = str.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g);
            $.post('application/getMenu.php',
                {item : replaced[1]},
                function(data) {
                    menuItems = data
                };
            });
            return {
                callback: function(key, options) {
                    var m = "clicked: " + key;
                    window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
                    },
                items: menuItems
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

This is a part of PHP code that sends ajax response:

```
    $toReturn = "";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $var = $row['category_name'];
        $toReturn .= "\"".$var."\": {name: \"".$var."\"},";
    }
    echo $toReturn . "\"quit\": {name: \"Quit\"}";
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is to load via ajax is only available for submenus.  There is a request for the top level to be dynamic via ajax as well.

https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/issues/574